# OpenVPN start & connect at boot time

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, openvpn

How to start & connect OpenVPN at boot time? Please note that we are using Android 6.0 and OpenVPN 0.6.73.

Using the paid Tasker app is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following [entries](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98276/open-an-app-on-startup-after-booting).Maybe this app will help you: [LIama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=de)
It can be as much as Tasker if not more and is free.If you upgraded OpenVPN, you have a function that will start the application automatically when rebooting.