# How to run an app on startup in background

Tags: applications, boot, auto-start

How to run an app on startup in background? For example glasswire, kaspersky run in startup, as well as show in top In notification bar tray.  I want to run Gom audio in background when start up & show up in tray automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98276/open-an-app-on-startup-after-booting?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to auto-launch an application in the background (without UI explicitly) is using the `am startservice -n command` together with [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) with applications such as Tasker and the like capable of registering a `BOOT_COMPLETED` signal.

Depending on the nature of the application (which may require root), you can set up this in Tasker:

*Note: The application needs to have **a defined service(s)** declared in manifest.xml file*

You can use [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html) (7 day trial available) to accomplish this:

**Objective: Auto start a defined application in background after boot**

**Profile (or Trigger)**

Create a Profile which allows triggering of the Task after boot:

- Go to Profiles Tab and click  "+"
- Event  → System  → Device Boot
- Tap back to exit from this window

**Task**

You will notice as soon as you exit, you will be prompted to link this Profile to a Task;

- Scroll all the way up the Task list select **"New Task + "**
- You can name this Task *AutoStart* or anything.
- Click **"+"** to add new Action
- Code  → Run shell → enter command `start the activity` (it can be the main activity of the app or certain parts e.g monitoring data in my example:
- *Using NetMonitor Mini (`info.kfsoft.android.TrafficIndicatorPro`) I may decide to auto start in background the data monitoring service, so in the command box I write: `am startservice -n info.kfsoft.android.TrafficIndicatorPro/.TrafficMonitorService` to start at boot.*
- If it needs needs root, remember to check the box accordingly.
- Press back the way all back until you exit Tasker (your profile is now saved and is ready for execution)

**Extras**: Give Tasker more priority (allow auto-start for Tasker, exclude from battery optimisations, task killers etc)

*Explanation: Soon after boot, the  action  starts the application in background)*

Comment: is there alternative free/ adware app?

Comment: Try with macrodroid..