# Apps not auto starting on Nokia G42 5G

Tags: auto-start, nokia

I've been using the Synology Drive app to sync folders between several PC's and Android phones. I recently got a new Nokia G42 5G (Android 14), which needs the same folders syncing. However, on the Nokia, the Synology Drive app would be flaky with syncing, having to manually open the app and run the sync tasks, which should run automatically. I got fed up with this and moved to Syncthing instead, only to find it has the same problem.

Syncthing has an option to 'start service automatically on boot', which the Nokia simply ignores. Opening the Syncthing app manually immediately causes the sync tasks to run. I can't see any power settings on the Nokia that might be preventing the app from running. I've also tried a third-party app 'Boot Apps' to run Syncthing on startup, which hasn't worked.

This does not occur on my Samsung A22 5G. Both of these apps run happily in the background and I never have to touch anything.

I've come to the conclusion that 'auto start' is broken on the Nokia, it would explain why both Synology Drive and Syncthing don't work without manual intervention. Any ideas as to why the Nokia is unable to start apps at startup?

Comment: The A22 is not running Android 14, or am I wrong? If it runs a different Android version that may be the important difference. May be the two mentioned apps are not yet fully Android 14 compatible.

Comment: The A22 is running Android 13... Hadn't really clocked that was different, or that it would matter. I'll look into whether Syncthing has issues on Android 14, but I doubt it - I think I would have come across that in my searches. I'll take a look.

Comment: I couldn't find any new restriction about auto-start on Android 14. For debugging, have you tried opening other apps using the "auto start" app? Otherwise, you may try [general automation apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98276/44325) (disclosure: I wrote the answer).